# Render Extjs elements into other frame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, extjs

I want to render Ext elements in an iframe.

In the page that is loaded into the iframe, I have a div element:

```
<div id="panel"></div>
```

When the iframe is loaded, I want to render an Ext panel into this div element.

So the page loaded into the iframe got a function which is executed on load:

```
console.log(parent.Ext.get("panel"));
console.log(document.getElementById("panel"));
console.log(new parent.Ext.dom.Element(document.getElementById("panel")));
parent.Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
    layout : 'fit',
    height : 200,
    width : 600,
    autoScroll: false,
    renderTo : new parent.Ext.dom.Element(document.getElementById("panel"))
});
```

The console messages are as follows:

```
null VM14143:10
<div id=​"panel">​…​</div>​ VM14143:11
D {el: D, dom: div#panel, id: "panel", $cache: Object, self: function…} VM14143:12
TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null
```

The TypeError is occuring no matter which of the three console.logs I put into renderTo: `renderTo: parent.Ext.get("panel")` or `renderTo: document.getElementById("panel")` or `renderTo: new parent.Ext.dom.Element(document.getElementById("panel"))`, but it does not occur when I remove the `renderTo` line completely.

Now, how can I render a panel into my div?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I modified my question and sincerely hope it is now understandable what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is wrong. Because when you do parent.Ext,
it will execute in parent scope than in current scope(which is iframe)
So what you need to do is, have ExtJS library loaded in the iframe as well, and execute the code.

Comment: The scope is exactly why I am trying to use parent.Ext, where the required stores, data preprocessing etc. are already done. It can't be healthy for the performance to do everything again in the iframe - loading the JS all over again, initializing, loading data.

Comment: The parent Ext dom scope is its own dom. It will not be bothered with iframes dom. Basically ExtJs is not built for iFrames. iFrames are not recommended for anything. But still if you want to go for iFrame, then loading the JS again is the best option.